# Different game behavior on different Android devices

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

- When I run my Unity game on S3 with android 4.3, everything works fine.
- When I move the app on a Tablet with android 4.1.2 then the game works fine but it doesn't connect to google, fb or ads services, it doesn't even try to connect like it wasn't programmed to do it. The tablet was of course connected to internet. Even without internet connection it should behave in a different way (return a bool) but it doesn't.
- On the other hand when I test the app on S6 with android 5.0.2, the app menu starts, it connects to services but when you press the button to load the level the game crashes...

I don't understand how the app can work so differently on different devices.

I have updated JAVA, ANDROID SDK to newest versions.

1. Could the reason be that I'm missing something in androidManifest?
2. Or that the app should be installed through the Play Store and now it is treated as untrusted?
3. Can a memory leak causse the app to crash? (but then I belive it should be the same on any device and it wouldn't explain the issue on the tablet).

**LogCat log while running on S6**. The app crashes from the line: E/Watchdog( 3549): !@Sync 865

```
E/bt-btif (13388): bta_av_str_stopped:audio_open_cnt=1, p_data ea084398
E/PersonaManagerService( 3549): inState():  stateMachine is null !!
E/WindowState( 3549): getStack: Window{db782a6 u0 com.android.contacts/com.andro
id.dialer.DialtactsActivity} couldn't find taskId=78 Callers=com.android.server.
wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1230 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaul
tDisplay:1834 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2363 com.a
ndroid.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedApp:5586
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/Zygote  ( 3434): MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote  ( 3434): v2
E/SELinux ( 3434): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: N
ULL, cateogry: NULL
E/bt-btif (13388): bta_av_link_role_ok hndl:x41 role:1, conn_audio:x1, bits:1, f
eatures:x8049
E/bt-btif (13388): btif_media_task_aa_handle_timer now_us 76657411948 less than
0
E/SamsungIME(12313):          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGE
D
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): mFolderCoverOpened: (true, true) -> true
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/Zygote  ( 3451): MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote  ( 3451): v2
E/SELinux ( 3451): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: samsung sensitivity: N
ULL, cateogry: NULL
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/DeviceInfo( 3451): csc = PLS
E/DeviceInfo( 3451): country = Poland
E/GamesNativeSDK( 3434): Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: ja
va.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.
NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.dkgames.The
Saw/app_.gpg.classloader/4da25210572e7e07ea67142ded62c42e.jar"],nativeLibraryDir
ectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/Watchdog( 3549): !@Sync 863
E/PowerManagerService( 3549): handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming fals
e
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
E/MotionRecognitionService( 3549):  handler : SCREEN_OFF end
E/SContext.CaeProvider( 3549): setAttribute() : attribute is null!
E/WifiNative-wlan0( 3549): do suspend true
E/bt-btif (13388): bta_av_str_stopped:audio_open_cnt=1, p_data ea0846dc
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/LSO     (11114): LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/Zygote  ( 3619): MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote  ( 3619): v2
E/SELinux ( 3619): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity:
NULL, cateogry: NULL
E/S-Physics( 3619): PhysicsEngineJNI JNI_OnLoad enter!!
E/S-Physics( 3619): Success find Class
E/S-Physics( 3619): PhysicsEngineJNI JNI_OnLoad Success
E/WaterDroplet_JniWaterDropletRenderer( 3619): JniWaterDropletRenderer is called

E/WaterDroplet_JniWaterDropletRenderer( 3619): native_Init_JNI is called
E/<< JOOON >> ( 3619): Call the native_Init_JNI
E/SamsungIME(12313):          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGE
D
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): mFolderCoverOpened: (true, true) -> true
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2927): rejecting buffer: bufWidth=2560, bufHeight=1440, front.
active.{w=1440, h=2560}
E/SamsungWindowManager( 3549): mCoreNumLockHelper.acquire
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
E/MotionRecognitionService( 3549):  handler : SCREEN_ON end
E/WifiNative-wlan0( 3549): do suspend false
E/ActivityThread(11131): Failed to find provider info for com.sec.android.chinah
oliday
E/bt-btif (13388): bta_av_link_role_ok hndl:x41 role:1, conn_audio:x1, bits:1, f
eatures:x8049
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/bt-btif (13388): btif_media_task_aa_handle_timer now_us 76701272713 less than
0
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/MotionRecognitionService( 3549):   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_USER_PRESENT
:: UNLOCK SCREEN
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/ActivityManager( 3549): checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
E/Zygote  ( 3681): MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote  ( 3681): v2
E/SELinux ( 3681): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: release sensitivity: N
ULL, cateogry: NULL
E/JavaBinder( 3549): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/JavaBinder( 3549): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/SamsungIME(12313):          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGE
D
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): mFolderCoverOpened: (true, true) -> true
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/Watchdog( 3549): !@Sync 864
E/Watchdog( 3549): !@Sync 865
E/audit   ( 4956): type=1701 msg=audit(1430213672.481:337): auid=4294967295 uid=
10209 gid=10209 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 pid=3478 comm="main" re
ason="memory violation" sig=11
E/InputDispatcher( 3549): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be
disposed!
E/WindowState( 3549): getStack: Window{db782a6 u0 com.android.contacts/com.andro
id.dialer.DialtactsActivity} couldn't find taskId=78 Callers=com.android.server.
wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1230 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaul
tDisplay:1834 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2363 com.a
ndroid.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedApp:5586
E/SamsungIME(12313):          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGE
D
E/SmartFaceService( 3549): mFolderCoverOpened: (true, true) -> true
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=202
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdeceea30
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=204
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd7ade5d0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1748
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xc95fcc40
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1751
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272390
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1753
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272450
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1754
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd2724c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1755
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272540
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1756
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272590
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1757
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272690
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1758
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd2727b0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1759
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272850
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1760
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd2728e0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1761
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272950
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1762
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272a00
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1763
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272ad0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1765
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272e50
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1767
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd272f00
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1769
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd275290
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=1771
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd275580
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6252
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdffe3700
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6254
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdffe37d0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6256
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd57878f0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6258
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd275570
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6260
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdffe3570
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=6262
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdffe3450
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=87
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd57b05c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=90
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd57b0cf0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=92
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd579b3c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=99
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd0fe9630
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=101
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd0fe9cd0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=239
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd27c4d40
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=759
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef46eb30
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=761
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef46eff0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=763
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef470460
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=765
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4708c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=768
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef470d20
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=771
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4751d0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=777
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda56c450
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=778
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda56c9e0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=779
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda56cf60
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=785
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef475e30
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=787
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4ba2c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=795
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdc2fd460
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=796
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdc2fd9f0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=798
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda676530
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=799
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda676ab0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=800
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda679050
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=801
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda6795d0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=802
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xda679b50
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=803
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd695100
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=810
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdff835f0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=813
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4d08c0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=818
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4d32b0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=808
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xe1f176f0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=811
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xe1f17cd0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=814
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xe1f17d80
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=821
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xdff235e0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=822
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd696570
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=823
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcd696af0
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=828
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4d3920
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=830
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4d3d80
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=832
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xef4da210
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=2515
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcc97ee00
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=2935
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xcca59c20
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->resourceId=9053
E/image-factory(13312): ImageFactory::Load() ticket->typePath.type=0xd276db20
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 62)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8974)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8983)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8985)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8987)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8989)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8991)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8995)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8997)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 8999)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9001)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9003)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9005)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9007)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9009)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9011)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9013)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9016)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9017)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9018)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9019)
E/resource-client(13312): ResourceClient::RequestResourceTicket() resourceId not
 found(Id: 9021)
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2927): rejecting buffer: bufWidth=2560, bufHeight=1440, front.
active.{w=1440, h=2560}
E/bt-btif (13388): bta_av_str_stopped:audio_open_cnt=1, p_data ea0845f8
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
E/bt-avp  (13388): opcode 0
^C
```

Comment: `Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints"` this seems to be the exception, have you researched it? Also, what 'Minimum API Level' do you have set in player properties?

Comment: Also, please don't use `unity` tag for question related to Unity game engine.

Comment: Thanks for editing and quick answer! I will check it. The minimum API which is set now is Android 2.3.1 (API Level 9). Could this cause any of the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device is different than others. this means that some devices have google play services, some do not support bluetooth etc etc

When installing an app to a device, it makes some choices as to what code this device will run, I'm not sure how you configure it on `Unity` (I hope it's the same) but when making an Android project manually you make some folders like `drawable-mdpi` or `layout-port`. Check if there is a file in a folder like that which is not created by you, it probably contains some "Hello World" code but when you install it on a device it chooses that layout instead of the one you expect so when your code runs it can't find expected layouts so it crashes.

This can explain the `resourceId error` you've been getting, although I can't be 100% sure.

In case you don't know what these folders are please read [Android - Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

It has nothing to do with not being installed from Google Play, as long as it installs, it should run without issue.

Android manifest shouldn't be an issue either, it would be a problem if the new version of android needed some new permission that you haven't entered, but I don't see such an error in your log.

If this app is big, memory could cause the game to crash if not handled properly, but the S6 has high specs and since the game has run on other devices I highly doubt that is the issue. Since the menu is working and it only crashes when you start the game, try commenting out code (`Unity` has code, right?) and find what line causes the crash.

Comment: Thank you a lot for good explanation. I will try everything you suggested and come back to you whether or not it helped.